# Multiaccess link shows two Designated Routers in Area 0

Tags: routing, ospf, protocol-theory, quagga

I have four Cumulus routers set up with a single ethernet connection from r3 -> r1 -> r2 - r4.

From r1, `show ip ospf` neighbor displays the following:

```
**Neighbor ID     Pri State           Dead Time Address         Interface            RXmtL RqstL DBsmL
3.3.3.3           1 Full/DR           38.449s 10.2.1.2        swp1:10.2.1.1            0     0     0
2.2.2.2           1 Full/DR           38.281s 10.7.1.2        swp3:10.7.1.1            0     0     0
**
```

Is this a valid state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have more than one broadcast link. A DR is per broadcast (or non-broadcast) link, not per area. You can have areas with no DRs, but broadcast links will have a DR (assuming multicast, not unicast, neighbors).

In your example, R3 is the DR for the R3-to-R1 link, and R2 is the DR for the R1-to-R2 link.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I took a look at RFC2328 and now this concept is very clear.